# JQuery Buttons plus variable value populate text form

Tags: jquery, forms, calculation

I'm battling to get a simple form with 3 buttons to ad their values to a variable and output the result in a text box. I have tried several things but with no luck, Please if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
<body>
    
      $curr_price = 4000; 
    
        
    <br>
    <hr/><form>
        <input type="text" name="result_test" id="result-c" value=""> 
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        <br>
        
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="value1" value=" 500" id="btnone" title="your-tooltip-here">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="value1" value="1000" id="BtnTwo">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="value2" value="1500" id="BtnThree">
    </form>
    
    
</body>
 <script>

    $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // Get val of btn
        let a = parseInt( $( this ).val() );

        // Get val of form imput
        var b = parseInt('<?=$curr_price; ?>');

        // Sanity check on b to make sure we are working with a number
        if ( isNaN( b ) )
            b = 0;

        // Do the addition and place value in form input
        $( '#result-c' ).val( a + b );

    });



    </script
```

Comment: `$curr_price = 4000; ` ? why is this not wrapped in PHP tags? Also, why would you need "sanity checks" in the frontend code for PHP values?

Comment: Hi @RokoC.Buljan . I have tried to wrapped it in PHP tags as well, same result. If I remove the sanity check it returns the value of the button with variable name next  to it in the text field. for example 1000$curr_price. I just don't know how to get the jQuery script to get the value of the variable. Do you have any suggestions.

Comment: Buttons don't have a value. Use input text/number for this

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap into PHP tags
- Import the jQuery library

`index.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $curr_price = 4000;
    ?>

    <hr />

    <form>
        <input type="text" name="result_test" id="result-c" value="">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        <br>

        <input class="btn" type="button" name="value1" value=" 500" id="btnone" title="your-tooltip-here">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="value1" value="1000" id="BtnTwo">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="value2" value="1500" id="BtnThree">
    </form>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // Get val of btn
        let a = parseInt($(this).val());

        // Get val of form imput
        var b = parseInt('<?= $curr_price; ?>');

        // Sanity check on b to make sure we are working with a number
        if (isNaN(b))
            b = 0;

        // Do the addition and place value in form input
        $('#result-c').val(a + b);

    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank You @Roko  but that is exactly my problem. The code you posted only return the value of the button and not the calculation result.

Comment: @RoelfKeulder so what should happen when I click the buttons? Always add? (Currently it replaces the old value with the new 4000+button value)

Comment: So, PHP's $curr_price is 4000, what should be the result after clicking buttons in this order: 1, 2, 3, 2, 1?? @RoelfKeulder

Comment: The $curr_price is a variable so it is different for different products I just use 4000 as an example, The button values are 1500, 1000 and 500. So if you press button 1 in my example which has the value of 1500 and my $curr_price value is at 4000 at that stage the result in the text box should be the calculation of the values 5500, which is the calculation of the variable $curr_price at that stage 4000 + 1500 the value of the button. If button 2 is clicked it should be 4000 + 1000 and it should show 5000 in the text box , and when button 3 is pressed it should show 4000 + 500.

Comment: What you described  **is exactly how the above works**. @RoelfKeulder.  
Seems you did not run the above on a PHP server - Since it uses PHP tags.  Open terminal, run `php -S localhost:8080` (from the folder where that index.php file is) and head in your browser to localhost:8080. See? It works.

Comment: Thank you again you are right. I am testing it on my local desktop using CodeLobster. I will upload it to my website and test it there. Thank you so much because it had me buffled

Answer (score 0):

@cloned I do not think the buttons values is the issue it is the value of the variable it does not import to the script correctly. If I have to change my last in the script to 'code' $('#result-c').val(a + 4000); my calculations works fine.